# Dictionary Comprehension Runtime Question

Tags: python, performance

I have a question about how to possibly optimize a dictionary comprehension.

Setup:

I'm dealing with looping over XML minidom objects.  Along with importing xml.dom.minidom I've defined a convenience function, getXMLDatum, in a custom package like so:

```
def getXMLDatum(container, elName):
        return container.getElementsByTagName(elName)[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

getXMLDatum simply "returns the value between the brackets" of a given (parent, child) couple in the XML document.

I have a list of distinct accounts that's around 300 items in size

```
In [1] len(accountNums)
Out[1] 285
```

I have a list of XML minidom objects that are denoted as "charge details", each of which contain a reference to exactly one account in accountNums

```
In [2] getXMLDatum(chargeDetails[0], "SECONDARY_ACCT")
Out[2] '00018608'
```

There are around 1500 charge details:

```
In [3] len(chargeDetails)
Out[3] 1426
```

I'm trying to create a mapping where I can plug in an account and get all the charge details associated with it:

```
In [4] accountMap = { account : [cd for cd in chargeDetails if getXMLDatum(cd, "SECONDARY_ACCT") == account] for account in accountNums }
```

It is heinously slow; it takes around 30 seconds in iPython in powershell.  Any ideas for how to speed it up?

Comment: The problem is the *algorithm* here. What sticks out to me is that you are doing `[cd for chargeDetails in cds if getXMLDatum(cd, "SECONDARY_ACCT") == account]` for every account. How to get around this depends on the details of the library you are using (I am not familiar with it), so you really should provide *those details*. list/dictionary comprehensions are just *syntactic sugar* for for-loops. They aren't an optimization.

Comment: What I suggest is simply looping over `chargeDetails` and using the normal dictionary grouping idiom

Comment: Is this supposed to be `cd for cd in cds` instead of `cd for chargeDetails in cds`? Otherwise, I don't see how your example wouldn't error out. If it isn't, you are probably referencing a global `cd` and there is a bug anyway

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Woops!  I was renaming variables and mistyped.  Good catch - I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly, you want something like:

```
account_map = {}
for cd in chargeDetails:
    account = getXMLDatum(cd, "SECONDARY_ACCT")
    if account not in account_map:
        account_map[account] = [cd]
    else:
        account_map[account].append(cd)
```

Which is the most naive way to group things using a dictionary. You could also use `.setdefault` or a `collections.defaultdict`, but the algorithm is fundamentally the same. But, for example:

```
account_map = {}
for cd in chargeDetails:
    account_map.setdefault(getXMLDatum(cd, "SECONDARY_ACCT"), []).append(cd)
```

would be another way to do it. But again, it's basically the same approach.

To contrast, here is the equivalent of what you were doing before with your `dict`/`list` comprehension:

```
accountMap = {}
for account in accountNums:
    temp_result = []
    for cd in chargeDetails:
        if getXMLDatum(cd, "SECONDARY_ACCT") == account:
            result.append(cd)
    accountMap[account] = temp_result
```

Notice, for every iteration that you do while you iterate over `accountNums`, you iterate over the entirety of `chargeDetails`, making it polynomial time. That is the issue.

Note, these will not be exactly equivalent if there are accounts that could get returned by `getXMLDatum` that aren't in `accountNums`, but you could just do something like:

```
account_map = {k:account_map[k] for k in (account_map.keys() & set(accountNums))}
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and it ran much faster.  Lesson learned: I was overcomplicating things with the dictionary comp.  I thought the comp would speed it up due to comps being specially implemented to run fast, but I ended up increasing the runtime category.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattGracz comprehensions **are not** specifically implemented to run fast, they are designed to express mapping/filtering operations in a *readable, declarative fashion*, but they aren't optimizations. The loops I showed you are basically exactly equivalent (with minor optimizations, e.g. no need to resolve `result.append` each iteration, there is a specific opcode for that, but the result is a marginal speedup, comprehensions are for readability not speed!)